# Click through to an existing E-Mail in editor mode possible?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I am trying to build a custom E-Mail search functionality using a Landing Page. It's meant to search through sent E-Mails and display not only the E-Mail but also offer a link to click through directly to the E-Mail editor. Following are the details/steps:

1. Build landing page (done).
2. Add new menu item and clicking on it display the landing page (done).
3. Do a search on sent email by 'Name' field and display the search result list (done).
4. Make the email name as clickable in result page (done).
5. Clicking on email name should open the email in edit mode like how its displayed  if its opened from Email list page (we are not able to achieve this, this where we need your help/support).